# sum of multiple products with show rows concerned using array

Tags: mysql, arrays, sum, rows, product

I have a table that has 3 products description (Product_1, Product_2, Product_3) and Each product of some reference AND quantity with location of every row

Iwant show all rows for product_1, product_2, product_3 which the sum of each product on Array variable as an example

```html
$globalProduct = array(21000, 18000, 1000);

$sumProduct_1 = $globalProduct[0];
$sumProduct_2 = $globalProduct[1];
$sumProduct_3 = $globalProduct[2];
```

Ihave query mysql for one product but I found it difficult to use 3 products.

this query for one product, it's working correctly

```html
SET @runtot=0;
SELECT p_reference, p_id, p_description, p_quantity, p_location, (@runtot := @runtot + p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM (
    SELECT p_reference, p_id, p_description, p_quantity, p_location
    FROM product_table
    WHERE p_description = 'product_1'
    ORDER BY p_reference, p_quantity
) AS l
WHERE @runtot <= 21000;
```

**this follow source code for create Product_table**

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_table` (
`p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `p_reference` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_location` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_quantity` float(11,3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;

--
-- Contenu de la table `product_table`
--

INSERT INTO `product_table` (`p_id`, `p_description`, `p_reference`, `p_location`, `p_quantity`) VALUES
(1, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'QD01', 7000.000),
(2, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'QD02', 7000.000),
(3, 'Product_1', '1A00007', 'QD03', 7000.000),
(4, 'Product_1', '1A00008', 'QD04', 7000.000),
(5, 'Product_2', '1A00002', 'AB01', 6500.000),
(6, 'Product_2', '1A00004', 'AB02', 6500.000),
(7, 'Product_2', '1A00005', 'AB03', 6500.000),
(8, 'Product_2', '1A00003', 'DB01', 6500.000),
(9, 'Product_2', '1A00009', 'DB02', 6500.000),
(10, 'Product_2', '1A00002', 'DB03', 6500.000),
(11, 'Product_2', '1A00002', 'DB04', 6500.000),
(12, 'Product_3', '1A00010', 'FD01', 5000.000),
(13, 'Product_3', '1A00015', 'DS02', 5000.000),
(14, 'Product_3', '1A00017', 'DS03', 5000.000),
(15, 'Product_3', '1A00018', 'DS04', 5000.000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is as easy as this?

```
SELECT
    p_description,
    sum(p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM
    product_table
GROUP BY
    p_description
```

Comment: This function gives us sum poduct_1 + product_2 + product_3 <= 21000, but I want sum every product <= 21000 with show all rows concerned

Comment: but not exist sum of every product, I want using this array. this is an example. $globalProduct = array(21000, 18000, 1000);

$sumProduct_1 = $globalProduct[0];
$sumProduct_2 = $globalProduct[1];
$sumProduct_3 = $globalProduct[2];

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a bit more complicated then:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT
    a.*, c.p_description as nextProduct,
    (@gc := @gc + a.p_quantity) as uu, if(a.p_description != c.p_description, @gc := 0, 1) as `reset`
  FROM
    (SELECT @gc := 0) as b, product_table as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN product_table as c ON a.p_id = c.p_id -1
) as a
WHERE uu <= 21000
```